# Closed form for $\int_0^\infty\frac{x-1}{(x+1)^3(x^t-1)}dx $ and explicit form for $\zeta(3)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Here $t$ is a real positive parameter, and I am trying to solve the following integral:
$$I_t=\int_0^\infty\frac{x-1}{(x+1)^3(x^t-1)}dx $$
This evaluation could lead (maybe) to an explicit form for $\zeta(3)$, given the following relation:
$$\zeta(3)=\frac{2\pi^2}{7}\lim_{t\to 0}t\cdot I_t $$
I tried letting $x\to\frac1{x}$, leading to
$$I_t=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^t(x-1)}{(x+1)^3(x^t-1)}dx$$
but seems to be worse. So I tried evaluating first the integral from $0$ to $1$ with $x$ in the numerator:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{x}{(x+1)^3(x^t-1)}dx & =-\int_0^1\frac{x}{(x+1)^3}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{kt}\right)dx \\
& =-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{x^{kt+1}}{(x+1)^3}dx \\
\end{align}
but now the integrals of the form $\int_0^1\frac{x^{\alpha}}{(x+1)^3}$ are tough themselves, and result in messy digamma functions, together with other terms, so I believe **this is not the way**.

I should add that **I am not looking for a proof of the limit** as I already have it. I am looking **only for a closed form of the integral**.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Using Mathematica to work out the power series in $t$ I obtained $$t\frac{x-1}{(x+1)^3 \left(x^t-1\right)}=\frac{x-1}{(x+1)^3 \log (x)}+O(t),$$
so formally at least your integral may be replaced by
$$\frac{7}{2\pi^2}\zeta(3)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x-1}{(x+1)^3 \log (x)}dt.$$

Comment: We can also get @pathfinder's restatement with L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @pathfinder . Nice, this confirms my result, but I still wonder if a closed form does exist for every $t$. Thank you.

Comment: @J.G. I tried using l'Hopital, but it was unsuccessful, could you provide some hint?

Comment: @Zima Construe $t/(x^t-1)$ as a function of $t$.

Comment: @pathfinder Your integral should be over $x$ instead of $t$?

Comment: I believe the integral can also be evaluated as the Laplace transform $\frac{7}{2 \pi^2}\, \zeta(3)=\mathcal{L}_x\left[\frac{e^x-2}{\log\left(e^x-1\right)}\right](2)=\int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{e^x-2}{\log \left(e^x-1\right)}\,  e^{-2 x} \, dx$.

Comment: I am skeptical about the idea that $I_t$ has a nice elementary closed form. For fun, we can check that $$t I_t = \frac{7\zeta(3)}{2\pi^2}+\frac{1}{12}t^2-\frac{\pi^2}{720}t^4+\frac{\pi^4}{12960}t^6-\frac{31\pi^6}{3628800}t^8+\cdots$$ near $t=0$.

Comment: Also, for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$, we can prove that $$I_k=\frac{2-(-1)^k}{6}k + \frac{\pi}{2k}\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\frac{k-1}{2}\rfloor} \frac{\sin(\pi j/k)}{\cos^3(\pi j/k)}\left(\frac{2j}{k}-1\right)$$ Considering that the last sum is often an algebraic number of high degree, I doubt the existence of a simple elementary closed-form of $I_t$.

Comment: @StevenClark yes that was a typo, but by the time I realised the 5 minutes had expired so I could not change it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only **closed form** solution with **Mathematica**,

using **Mellin Transform** and **Inverse Mellin Transform**:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x-1}{(x+1)^3 \left(x^k-1\right)} \, dx=\\\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\mathcal{M}_A\left[\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x-1}{(x+1)^3 \left(A x^k-1\right)} \,
   dx\right](s)\right](1)=\\\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\int_0^{\infty } \mathcal{M}_A\left[\frac{x-1}{(x+1)^3 \left(A x^k-1\right)}\right](s) \,
   dx\right](1)=\\\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{\pi  (-1+x) \left(-x^k\right)^{-s} \csc (\pi  s)}{(1+x)^3} \, dx\right](1)=\\\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[(-1)^{-s} k^2 \pi
   ^2 s^2 \csc (\pi  s) \csc (k \pi  s)\right](1)=\\\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{(-1)^{-s} k^2 \Gamma (1-s) \Gamma (k s) \Gamma (1+s)^2 \Gamma (1-k s)}{\Gamma (s)}\right](1)=\\\pmb{k{}^{\wedge}2*\text{FoxH}[\{\{\{0,1\},\{1,-k\},\{0,k\}\},\{\}\},\{\{\{1,1\},\{1,1\}\},\{\{1,-1\}\}\},-1]}$$

MMA code:

`k^2*FoxH[{{{0, 1}, {1, -k}, {0, k}}, {}}, {{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, -1}}}, -1]`

Answer (score 2):

*Just for the fun of using (once more) my favored $1,400^+$ years old approximation of the sine function.*

Starting from @Lai solution
$$J=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{x-x^2}{\sin (\pi x)}\,dx=\frac 1{2\pi^2}\int_0^\pi \frac{(\pi -t)\, t} { \sin (t)}\,dt$$
Using
$$\sin(t) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -t) t}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -t) t}\qquad \text{for} \qquad 0\leq t\leq\pi$$

$$J\sim \frac 1{32\pi^2}\int_0^\pi \left(4 t^2-4 \pi  t+5 \pi ^2\right)\,dt=\frac{13 \pi }{96}$$ (relative error of $0.2$%) which would then give as an approximation
$$\zeta(3) \sim \frac{13 \pi ^3}{336}$$ for an absolute error of $0.0024$.

This is slightly worse than the apparoximation
$$\zeta(3)\sim \frac{\pi ^3 }{3 \sqrt{105}}\left(\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)+\sec
   \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)\right) $$ which was [proposed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4701752/is-this-reasonable-closed-form-approximation-for-the-value-of-zeta3-using-t) on the site.

Comment: Interesting approximation!

Comment: @Lai. When I see a sine, I cannot resist ! Cheers. By the way, nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by J.G., we can try to interchange the limit and the integral sign and get

$$
J= \lim _{t \rightarrow 0} t \cdot I_t=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x-1}{(x+1)^3}\left(\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{t}{x^t-1}\right) d x
$$
By L’Hospital Rule, we have

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{t}{x^t-1}  =  \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^t \ln x} = \frac{1}{\ln x}
$$
Hence $$
J=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x-1}{(x+1)^3 \ln x} d x
$$
Now consider a parameterized integral
$$
J(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a-1}{(x+1)^3 \ln x} d x
$$
Differentiating $J(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ kills $\ln x$ and yields
$$
J^{\prime}(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{(x+1)^3} d x
$$

Letting $ y=\frac{1}{x+1}$ transforms the integral into a Beta function
$$
\begin{aligned}
J^{\prime}(a) & =\int_0^1 y^{1-a}(1-y)^a d y \\
& =B(2-a, a+1)\\&=\frac{\Gamma(2-a) \Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(3)} \\
& =\frac{(1-a) \Gamma(1-a) a \Gamma(a)}{2} \quad (\textrm{ Using }\Gamma(1+z)=z\Gamma (z)) \\
& =\frac{(1-a) a}{2} \pi \csc (\pi a) \quad (\textrm{ Using Reflection Prop. of Gamma function.)}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Integrating back from $a=0$ to $1$ yields
$$
J=J(1)=J(1)-J(0)=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{x-x^2}{\sin (\pi x)} d x
$$

---

Now we are going to evaluate the last integral by Euler identity and power series.
$\displaystyle \begin{aligned} \int_0^1 \frac{x-x^2}{\sin (\pi x)} d x & =2 i \int_0^1 \frac{x-x^2}{e^{\pi x i}-e^{-\pi x i} d x} \\& =2 i \int_0^1 e^{-\pi x i}\left(x-x^2\right) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-2 n\pi  x i} d x \\& =2 i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \underbrace{ e^{-(2n+1) \pi x i}\left(x-x^2\right) d x}_{K_n} \end{aligned}\tag*{} $
Integration by parts twice yields
$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}K_n& =-\frac{1}{(2 n+1) \pi i} \int_0^1(x-x^2)  d\left(e^{-(2 n+1)\pi xi}\right) \\&=\frac{1}{(2 n+1) \pi i} \int_0^1(1-2 x) e^{-(2 n+1)\pi xi} dx\\&=-\frac{1}{(2 n+1)^2 \pi^2} \int_0^1(1-2 x)d\left(e^{-(2 n+1)\pi xi}\right) \\& =-\left[\frac{(1-2 x) e^{-(2 n+1) \pi x i}}{(2 n+1)^2 \pi^2}\right]_0^1+\frac{2}{2n+1)^2 \pi^2} \int_0^1 e^{-(2 n+1) \pi x i} d x \\& =\frac{e^{-(2n+1) \pi i}+1}{(2 n+1)^2 \pi^2}-\frac{2}{(2 n+1)^2 \pi^2} \cdot \frac{e^{-(2 n+1) \pi i}-1}{(2 n+1) \pi i} \\& =\frac{4}{(2 n+1)^3 \pi^3 i} \end{aligned}\tag*{} $
where $e^{-(2n+1) \pi i}=-1.$

Now we can go back
$\displaystyle J=2 i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{4}{(2 n+1)^3 \pi^3 i}=\frac{8}{\pi^3} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n+1)^3}=\frac{7 \zeta(3)}{\pi^3}\tag*{} $

---

Hence we can conclude that
$$
\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} t \cdot I_t =\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{7 \zeta(3)}{\pi^3}=\frac{7 \zeta(3)}{2 \pi^2}
$$
and consequently
$$
\boxed{\zeta(3)=\frac{2 \pi^2}{7} \lim _{t \rightarrow 0} t \cdot I_t}
$$

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I was asking.

Comment: I believe zima was aware of $\zeta(3)$ being expressed as that limit; that's why they asked the question. The challenge is to figure out $I_t$ so that the limit can be evaluated differently in the hopes of an expression for $\zeta(3)$